# Creating a custom input device for a DTrack wand, using both the new and old input system in Unity 2021

Tags: unity, input

I am currently trying to figure out how to bridge the gap between the old input system and the new one. There is a DTrack wand that I am using, that has a package. Right now, I have a game that is setup for VR, but I want to have a second version that uses this DTrack wand as a controller. I would preferably like it to use the same inputs as an Oculus controller, basically having similar functionality for basic things, like the trigger, and a few of the buttons as well. The main problem is that there is no way for me to actually be able to connect the Dtrack controller directly to the computer, so the only way that its inputs are being read is through the pre setup Dtrack Unity package. Has anyone had any experience with this before, or know how I can proceed? I've linked the package below as well, so that you can take a look.

https://github.com/ar-tracking/UnityDTrackPlugin